# Local variables underline when reallocating in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, underline

When reallocating local variables in Android Studio, why is the underline under the variable name?
I think because functional programming does not recommend reassigning variables.
Is it right?

Underline is created in defaultDicWordDuplicationFlag variable

```
boolean defaultDicWordDuplicationFlag = false;

for (DicWord item: outDefaultDicWords) {
    if (item.word.equals(dicword.word)) {                           
        defaultDicWordDuplicationFlag = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (defaultDicWordDuplicationFlag == true)
    continue;
```

Comment: The irony is that the worst piece of English in your question is `"baaaaad"`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the highlight for a reassigned variable. A small hint to prefer immutable values.

You can change the setting in Android Studio preferences as shown in the image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks perfect answer : )